# Why does wine not support kernel mode driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, wine

I was trying to install league of legend using wine and I stumble upon this

> ANTICHEAT CHANGES IN 2021 WILL BREAK LoL PERMANENTLY, SEE BELOW.
>
> In 2021, Riot plans to introduce a kernel-mode driver as part of their
> anticheat[1]. This is fundamentally incompatible with wine and will be
> the end of League on Linux (using a virtual machine with GPU
> passthrough may still be supported). If you are a new player
> considering picking up League, we recommend against it.

> from https://lutris.net/games/league-of-legends/

Why do they choose to block this driver, and is a way to hijack this?

Comment: Wine does support kernel mode drivers, provided they are just "software" and don't interact with hardware devices (there's ReactOS for that otherwise). Just see how it can run safedisc and starforce games, often better than modern windows itself. But anti-cheat purpose is exactly verifying your system, of course a completely different operating system trips it.

Comment: @mirh so i guess the system should accept linux as a valid system xD (makes me wonder if there could be an way to assert that it's indeed interfacing with the linux kernel and not some random process)

Comment: [Winelib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937291/advantage-of-winelib) sounds exactly what you are looking for (even though the ways of the wine are very badly documented, and I'm not sure if the thing couldn't have been [deprecated](https://www.winehq.org/announce/6.0) by all their new PE/unix separation design effort).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple version.  Wine runs Windows programs without a Windows Kernel of any sort.

Wine provides an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) to match the userland API of Windows, but under the hood it does not, and never has had the internal Kernel mode API to simulate the *inner workings* of Windows.  That is it only simulates the way the Windows kernel *looks like* it behaves, not the way it *actually* behaves.

Moreover kernel mode drivers often contain code which is restricted by the CPU in userland.  This can include CPU [Opcodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opcode) for hardware access.  For wine to allow this code to run it would need to either:

- Emulate a CPU.  This is both slower and a lot of work.  It usually needs very specialist tools like [qemu](https://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page)
- Run the Windows driver (somehow) inside the Linux kernel.  Doing this safely would be almost impossible.

Since Wine does neither of these things, it's just not possible for them to provide this feature.

---

Having played LoL myself, I'm not surprised Riot have taken this action.  The last time I played, some game modes (particularly "all random") had excessive bot players screwing the games up for everyone.

Locking it down in the most tricky way possible is designed to make it as difficult as possible to run LoL on another platform.  It is designed make it only interface with windows so it won't interface with bots.

Comment: A third possibility is to run the Windows driver in user space with some small support in the kernel for the privileged instructions ...

Comment: @MurrayJensen: code for that small support still arrives at the 2nd option. Privileged insns mean the code would have to share the I/O operations (at least) with the host kernel. IMO this could be done only by integrating the WDM support into the Linux kernel. So the sharing of low-level resources is under single control. And that would be a huge task. Something like that but done vice versa (ie. for Windows kernel) is done in coLinux project. And still it uses an emulated devices, not a direct access to the real hardware.

Comment: Now I also remembered another kind of software which allows running Windows kernel mode drivers on *nix systems, but only for the specific type of drivers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NDISwrapper#Architecture

Comment: Another project targeting the single one kernel-mode driver `ntfs.sys` from a single Windows build (XP SP1a) which was called _Captive-NTFS_. Just take a look at how much implementation effort it required : http://www.jankratochvil.net/project/captive/doc/Components.pm

Comment: OK, maybe not so small :-) ... but you only need to emulate the bits your target driver needs (as NDISwrapper shows) - and you could do most of it in user mode as part of WINE.